# I cant run this program in eclipse but it works on JGRASP

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have the following code that makes an abstract class, concrete class that extends abstract class and a main method. There are no errors as it compiles and run fine in JGRASP. when I run in eclipse, it is just not running, but no errors produced. I named the file Product.java.

Here is the code:

```
abstract class Product {
    int value;

    public Product(int val) {
        value = val;
    }

    abstract public int multiply(int n);
}

class TimesTwo extends Product {
    public TimesTwo(int val) {
        super(val);
    }

    @Override
    public int multiply(int n) {
        return value * n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimesTwo two = new TimesTwo(5);
        System.out.println(two.multiply(5));
    }

}
```

I also try to run on commandline:

```
javac Product.java
```

I get `Product.class` and `TimesTwo.class`

and when I run 
`Java TimesTwo.class` or `Java Product.class`

I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

Comment: Works for me.  How are you running the program in Eclipse?  I am right-clicking on TimesTwo -> Run as -> Java App.

Comment: when the file was named Product.java, how can you run it? I need to seperate out as Reimeus mentioned below to make it work and how did you get TimesTwo from eclipse. Since you have only file named Product.Java..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `TimesTwo.java` exists as a separate Java source file before running in `Eclipse`.

Comment: Actually, this worked for me even when the file was named Product.java

Comment: Didnt even offer a run configuration for me until I separated it out :)

Comment: I clicked on the class itself, not the file. Maybe that's the difference

Comment: @Reimeus it worked, but why should I separate out.  Is it because, of the abstract class. If I have parent class and subclasses, it works fine without separating out.

Comment: No, Eclipse expects a `main` method in the class `Product` itself, i.e. the actual name of the file. If you added a dummy `main` method you would be offered 2 run configurations - one for each class. The command line interpreter doesnt have this restriction

Answer (score 0):

You should change `TimesTwo` to `public class` and try to run command as below:

```
java TimesTwo
```

There is no `.class` at the ending when running a class